# Why are my counter variables not displaying zero? c#

Tags: c#, loops, char

Every time i run this code, my counting variables always start at 48. I have them clearly initialized at 0. I am assuming this has something to do with reading in my char variable? Am i stuck reading input as a string and converting it to char?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace CountLowers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char choice;
            int otherCounter = '0';
            int lowerCounter = '0';

            do
            {
                WriteLine("Enter an Upper or Lower Case Charactor");
                Write("or Enter the '}' key to stop and view results > ");
                choice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

                if (Char.IsLower(choice))
                {
                    WriteLine("\n\n\t" + choice + " is a Lower Case Character\n");
                    lowerCounter = lowerCounter + 1;
                }
                else if (choice != '}')
                {
                    WriteLine("\n\n\tYou did not enter a Lower Case Character\n");
                    otherCounter = otherCounter + 1;
                }            
                else
                {
                    WriteLine("\n\n\tRESULTS\n");
                    WriteLine("You typed in " + lowerCounter + " Lower Case Charactors");
                    WriteLine("\nYou typed in " + otherCounter + " Other Charactors");
                }
            } while (choice != '}');

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int otherCounter = '0';` how that going to compile?
c# is very strict that it will not compile if it does have an error and that is an error

Comment: @Beginner Implicit cast from `char` to `int`

Comment: Whether it works or not... Why would you do that? Just use the number zero.

Comment: The program compiled. I'm using visual studio.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a zero character `'0'` instead of an integer zero.  Remove the single quotes.

```
    int otherCounter = 0;
    int lowerCounter = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks. I know it was something simple I was missing. I appreciate the positive solution. Not sure why other posters couldn't have been as helpful. (less rude)